# How I do I calculate the price of a Token as the amount of the token bought increases

Tags: remix, ether, solidity-0.8.x, function, math

Let say I created a Min price = 0.00056 ether for 150 coins which is the Min amount and the Max price = 0.1 for 20,000 coins which is the Max amount. What will be the price of the coin when I buy 1000 coins. And note the price must not go below the Min price and exceed the Max price.

Comment: on which platform?

Answer (score 0):

Bruh, what you gunna call the coin.. call it Pussy Protocol or something good

```
  def calculate_token_price(num_coins: int) -> float:
     """

min_amount = 150
max_amount = 20000
min_price = 0.00056
max_price = 0.1

 
   excess_coins = max(num_coins - min_amount, 0)


    price_increment = (max_price - min_price) / (max_amount - min_amount)


   price_per_coin = min_price + excess_coins * price_increment


  total_price = num_coins * price_per_coin

    return total_price
```